# how to convert stringified JSONObject[] to JSONObj[] in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have `JSONObject[]` in stringified format. I need to convert it back to `JSONObject[]` in java how I can achive that??

**Sample Code :**

```
 JSONObject[] json = new JSONObject[10];

 String jsonStrArray = "[{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3}]";

 JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) 
      parser.parse(strFinalRecord).getAsJsonObject();

 json = jo;
```

**Error:**

```
incompatible type 
Required : org.json.JsonObject[]
Found : com.google.gson.JsonObject
```

If it is getting `gson.JsonObject` how to can I cast it to `JsonObject[]` ?
Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: you are using json object from org.json jar instead of using gson jar

Comment: you are using JSONObject from org.json and JsonObject from com.google.gson. using same library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json String you have created is not formatted correctly. 
Try the following code.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws ParseException {
         JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

         String jsonStrArray = "[{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\",\"c\":\"3\"},{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\",\"c\":\"3\"},{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\",\"c\":\"3\"}]";

         JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
         JSONArray jo = (JSONArray) parser.parse(jsonStrArray);
         System.out.println(jo);
         json.put("key", jo);
         System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Use JSON-Simple